# How do I divide up food among multiple agents?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have two agent types in my model `food` and `foragers`.

Food can come in different `amounts` and foragers have different stomach `capacities`.

The difficulty arises when multiple foragers arrive at some food at the same time. I want to make sure they don't get more food than is available.

I'm not sure how to tackle this. Here's some pseudo code of my attempts.

```
ask food [if any? foragers-here] set amount amount - count foragers-here ; but this misses the capacity of the foragers

ask forager [if any? food-here [set state feeding] 
ifelse [state = feeding & amount > capacity] [set my-energy capacity] [set my-energy amount]
```

I suspect it'd be easier to have one global variable that I can account for rather than having it split into different elements.

Comment: "The difficult arises when multiple foragers arrive at some food at the same time." 

This sounds a bit like a race condition. If this is psuedocode, you can assume that a lock is placed on distinct instances of food such that only one forager can feed at any time, or atomically remove the amount of food a forager could possibly consume (based on their capacity) from the total food.

Comment: So create a queue of foragers or something like that? The co-occurrence of foragers isn't all that rare because I had them extracting food at a rate, rather than instantaneous consumption.

Comment: That would work. It really depends on what you want to achieve. To be as realistic as possible, any number of foragers can atomically remove one food unit from the food instance. You could implement this as a forager acquiring a lock on the food instance, removing one from the total food count, and then releasing the lock on the food, then repeating this sequence of actions as many times as they can after having eaten. This would be a more accurate simulation an ongoing 'feeding' state.

Comment: I'm not sure what language you are emulating with your psuedocode here, so it's difficult to say exactly how this implementation would work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it is NetLogo I'm working with.